# How to pass Data From JQuery AJAX to PHP Without submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass a data `data: ( {name: 'ccenter', value: 'Sales Department' } )` using AJAX JQuery into PHP page Without any submission.
I try with `session_name(); session_start();` But It didn't work.variable `$ccenter` still remains undefined.I think i have missed some code to do so.please help me.Thanks

Here Is my Jquery AJAX Code:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'empid_list.php',
        type: "post",
        async:true,
        data: ( {name: 'ccenter', value: 'Sales Department' } ), 
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#employeeid').html(data);
        }
    });    
});
```

And Here Is my PHP File code:

```
<?php
    session_name('session1'); 
    session_start();    
    $ccenter = $_POST['ccenter'];   
?>
```

Comment: $ccenter = $_POST['ccenter']; or $ccenter = $_POST['name'];??

Comment: should be `$_POST['name']` instead of `$_POST['center']` (because of key -> value association) and you should echo something back from php, else `data` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Any errors in console ? Did you try checking data by print_r($_POST) on our server side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data format is wrong ,must be `{data-name:data-value}`

```
data: {name: 'ccenter', value: 'Sales Department' }
```

So you should call by data-name

```
$ccenter = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: Glad to hear that !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use javascript dataform objects:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("ccenter", "Sales Department");


$.ajax({
           url: 'empid_list.php',
           type: "post",
           async:true,
           data: formData, 
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data) {
               $('#employeeid').html(data);
           }
      });
```

Comment: Is FormData supported by all browsers?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Basic support (no file attaching) in: Chrome 7+, Firefox 4.0+, Internet Explorer 10+, Opera 12+, Safari 5+ 

Check it out: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#Browser_compatibility)